# Welcome email after user reset password in first time?

Tags: users, emails

When a new user signs up with the website the user receives an email with link to reset the password and when they reset the password first time, they get a welcome email but when in future they reset their password , they will not get that welcome email.How to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by using [Login one time](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_one_time) module

> Rules:
>
> - `[user:login-one-time]` token on user events.
> - `[comment:login-one-time]` token for node author on comment event.
>
> User profile - "Send login one time link" button.
>
> VBO - Create a view and send login links to the view. Checkout View
>   Reference for ideas on how to embed views.
>
> Block - Select a user and send the link. You can use this block in
>   nodes as a CCK field using Block Reference.
>
> PHP - Print a button in a template or directly send the emails using
>   the functions described in the README.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [Recovery Password](https://www.drupal.org/project/recovery_pass) module.

> Drupal by default sends Password Reset URL by mail to user's email id
>   in password recovery mail, but Recovery Password module makes it
>   possible for Drupal to send any random generated password(new
>   password) by email instead of URL to the user.

Comment: How to know user is first time user ?

Comment: I think by default it is 24 hours,if you increase the time period in will works.

Comment: But user will have option to reset password anytime.and i have to send welcome email after resetting password for first time.

Comment: Means issue is when user  reset the password they will not receive email right !

Comment: only first time recieve email .but when in future they reset their password , they will not get that email.

Comment: please update your question with this comment. so other user will easily understand and you will get best solution.

Comment: updated my answer you can try the new one.

Comment: Now i have updated. Do you have solution for my problem ?

Comment: check ''/admin/config/people/accounts'' section and try the module i have posted.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to answer this question is to use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, similar to what is described in either of these comments in the issue with title "[Rule to redirect on login, except on one-time login and password reset](https://www.drupal.org/node/480584)":

- [comment # 34](https://www.drupal.org/node/480584#comment-7897937):

> - **Event**: User logged in.
> - **Conditions**:
>
>   - *Elements*: Text comparison.
>   - *Parameter*: Tekst: [site:current-page:path], Matching text: user, Comparison operation: ends with

- [comment #37](https://www.drupal.org/node/480584#comment-9626805)

> - **Event**: User logged in.
> - **Conditions**:
>
>   - *Elements*: NOT Text comparison.
>   - *Parameter*: Text: [site:current-page:path], Matching text: ^user/reset/, Comparison operation: regular expression

Obviously, for either approach mentioned in these 2 comments, you'd have to add a **Rules Action** to actually send an appropriate eMail message also.

**Note**: If you're not familiar (enough/yet) with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), checkout the 32 (!!!) great, and free, video tutorials [Learn the Rules framework](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-the-rules-framework).